# Angular recognize imports from root?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, es6-modules

I have a simple service which uses Inject/Injectable  :

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_CONFIG} from '../../config/app-config.module';
import {AppConfig} from '../models/core/app-config.model';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config:AppConfig) {
    }
}
```

Nothing new here , however -as we know -  I must import `Inject, Injectable`.

Even If I would've imported `Inject, Injectable` at the root module - still I had to import those in the file.

OK.

But now I'm facing a situation (code is not mine) where a developer imported some RXJS operators at the root folder :

**rxjs-imports.ts**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/shareReplay'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/pluck'
```

[image]

Then he imported the file in `app.module.ts` :

```
import './rxjs-imports';
```

And now he can use those operator *without importing them(!)* at another component/service :

```
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
//no imports for operators
  public get<T>(name: string) :Observable<T>{
        return this.subj.pluck( "d");     <---- how does it knows pluck ?
    }
```

**Question:**

I don't understand - how come it's working ? I was expected that the compiler will yell to add the `pluck` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/xxx'` actually patches the `Observable` prototype and extends it with the specified operators, thus importing the files ones results in being able to use those operators with every `Observable` in your code from then on.

You can see how it is done in the RxJS source code, for example the [catch](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/c1721e3dd582c509064e141425c15622f68d60cb/src/add/operator/catch.ts#L5) operator.